# Is there any reason of restlessness in the afternoon?

Tags: mindfulness

I have been practicing mindfulness and watching thoughts.   I usually feel rapture, calm and desireless all the day but not in afternoon after lunch.  In afternoon, I even forget all stability including mindfulness & various desires creeps in the mind. Situations become extraordinarily better after 4-4:30PM.

Is there any particular reason of afternoon (2-4) instability? What can I do to let that not happen?

Comment: Is this question inviting physiological (medical) explanations and suggested counter-measures?

Answer (score 1):

Restless drowsiness is common after eating. [AN7.61](https://suttacentral.net/an7.61/en/thanissaro) discusses remedies at length, including:

> But if by doing this you don’t shake off your drowsiness, then—percipient of what lies in front & behind—set a distance to meditate walking back & forth, your senses inwardly immersed, your mind not straying outwards. It’s possible that by doing this you will shake off your drowsiness.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not about your mindfulness, it just the habit. We used to that way of life cycle for infinite long time. Just because we are practicing meditation for few hours of day about month or year, that habit cannot break instantly. Just forget about those thoughts. It's actually good, cause you know that your mind is not controlled by your self. And your still focus on mind that's how your know,

> forget all stability including mindfulness & various desires creeps in the mind

be patient and practice meditation whenever you can

Answer (score 0):

It could just be subconscious stress. Your suppressed negative emotions have nowhere to go so they materialize themselves in this way. Maybe you should try a physical way of venting stress like running.

Answer (score 0):

Our hormone levels changes during different times of the day. Mostly after having the lunch, the blood flows tend to direct to food digestion & hormone levels do drop during the day time. This could majorly influence in not being able to concentrate. 
Better go through the time table of Buddha's life to find a better way to live in mindfulness without feeling instable.
May the nobel triple gem bless you in your path.